# How to upload annotations and images in CVAT using Postman?

Tags: rest, annotations, postman, swagger, cvat

I am able to create a new project, create a new task inside the project using CVAT Swagger and POSTMAN. But when it comes to uploading images or annotations, the APIs are not working. It is giving following error:

[image: Error while uploading Annotations]

Can someone please help me by sharing the working payload and endpoint that needs to be sent for uploading images and annotations. CVAT documentation and SWAGGER API doesn't help either.